# angular authentication with token and signature

Tags: angular, authentication, token, graphql, apollo

i have `graphql-go` api using authentication, it already work when i test it with 
**curl**

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Token: someS3cr3tT0ken" \
  -H "Signature: FAC2CA55E128AB2E399474200121DB19442324D7DFF40A919865130DC1A2409" \
  --data '{"transaction_id": "123", "query": "query {validate(phonenumber:\"XXXXXXXXX\") {request_id}}" }' \
  http://localhost:6060/validate
```

the response whould be :

`{"data":{"validate":{"request_id":"22421462-4a3e-43c7-b188-57b6fe1c5575"}}}`

but i want to implement it in angular with apollo client,. so, in essence,, **is it possible to convert the `curl` command above in angular http request...?** 
I already tried using interceptor and clone the http request and modify the header but i only be able to set the `headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", "someS3cr3tT0ken"` and then i combine with the second interceptor with `headers: request.headers.set("Signature", "FAC2CA55E128AB2E399474200121DB19442324D7DFF40A919865130DC1A2409"`when i did this it give me `400 badRequest` its an error response the server give me when either of the argument `curl` above are incorrect, thing is,, i actually just shot in the dark, and dont really know how to set `3 Header parameter` in angular, ,most of the resource i found was to `getToken from localStorage` which doesnt work in my case, since i cant provide the `Header signature`

**Update**
here is my interceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class graphqlInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any> , next: HttpHandler){
        const newRequest = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set("Token", "someS3cr3tT0ken")
       // or
      // headers: request.headers.set("Authorization","someS3cr3tT0ken")
      //neither of the option above are working.
        return next.handle(newRequest)
```

and then i create the second interceptor to assign the `Signature:` ,,

[image]
here is the result of the implementation above.. i know you would think this is CORS problem from the server, but if i change `Token` to `Authorization`
the response change to bad request[image]

here is the details XHR [image]

thanks . .

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your interceptor? New HttpHeaders are immutable, everytime you set a new header value, you get a new reference. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders

Comment: thanks for the response @SamiAI90, i've update my question. .please check it out. .

Comment: Please provide the code of the second interceptor, a screenshot of the http request from your browsers dev tools and the complete error response. So we can see what headers have been sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my team suggest that i need to put `express.js` in the middle, so from `angular` `->` req to `express` and then process the `req` and pass it to `graphql-server`and it works.